# Actual KPI values Sharepoint Dashboard Designer are Calculating Weirdly

Tags: sharepoint, dashboard-designer

I am attempting to build a simple SharePoint Scorecard using the Dashboard Designer. The underlying list is an OOB Task List and the measured dimension is %-complete.

Each task obviously has a 1-100%. As a test KPI the goal for all "Assigned To" persons is to reach 100%. Ideally, in the future each person will have their own KPI and scorecard that can be adjusted, there will be a team roll up scorecard and all of those will roll into a dashboard.

However, I am struggling because when I create the KPI the "Actual" values seem to be multiplying by some weird factor.

Does anyone know why the actual values are showing as so large? I've tried other calculations than default and the values don't really change.

http://wayfaring.io/fotos/Screenshots/KPI-Issues.png

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. It turns out that the underlying calculation *of the data in the list* needs to be changed from "SUM" to "Average".

Within the workspace browser (left pane) of Dashboard Designer under your Data Connections go into the list that populates your scorecard. Then go to the View tab. If you click Preview Data you can see the head of the dataset. Under the %-complete the default calculation is "SUM". Click that column header and then on the right pane (Details) change the Aggregation parameter from SUM to Average.

Save your changes and refresh the KPI in the score card and now I see the appropriate %-completes for each user.

Voila!